# I have found a bug when I click on the StackExchange menu and other buttons

Tags: support

I just found this bug when I clicked on the StackExchange button and other buttons. Some orange-dotted lines appear around the button when I click on it.

Here are some screenshots:[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thats inevitable, and not a bug.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I was allowed to report stuff like that.

Comment: Well its something your browser does, not the site itself, that what i wanted to say, reporting things is still fine, just wanted to point out that it is not a big on the site. Though I think if it would be a serious bug (e.g. security concerned one) you should rather mail to them as instead posting it here. :)

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: When I saw the screenshots, I thought for a second you were running XP :) Then I looked more closely.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with the Lubuntu desktop installed on top of it. Then I added a Windows XP theme and then added a gnome-like panel on top of the screen. Linux is bomb when it comes to customization!

Comment: that is a feature of firefox.

Comment: @AndroidDev wait, it's not... Looks really realistic.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Especially at first glance.

Comment: @AndroidDev Of course if he was really running Windows XP it would be like that scene in 300 when they go "This is madness.. This is blasphemy"...

Comment: For some reason I just like the Luna theme from Windows XP, brings back a lot of memories....

Comment: @TheChosenOne99 i understand, I feel the same with old Mac OS 7 and 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one posted an answer on this so it can get closed I'm now putting my comments into an answer:

Well its something your browser does, not the site itself, thats inevitable, and not a bug.

Reporting things is still fine and encouraged, but please remind if it is a serious bug or security risk it would be better to mail it directly to the SE team instead of posting it here.